# How to deploy a React SSR app that doesn't use Next.js to AWS Amplify?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, server-side-rendering, aws-amplify

AWS released SSR support on May 18th, 2021: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/05/aws-amplify-hosting-announces-server-side-rendering-support-for-next-js-web-apps/

I've been able to deploy a **Next.js** app without any issues, however, when attempting to deploy a custom React SSR app, I'm not sure how to do it, and there doesn't appear to be any documentation / blogs about it... is it even possible?

For example, here is my `ampify.yml` file:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Here is the relevant scripts from my `package.json` file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prod::ssr": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production MODE=ssr webpack",
    "prod::client": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production MODE=client webpack",
    "build": "npm run prod::ssr && npm run prod::client",
    "start": "node dist/ssr/index.js"
  },
```

This works fine locally, but not on AWS Ampify.

My understanding is AWS Ampify uses the `start` command to run the app... is this true?

Comment: Consider using CloudFront with S3 bucket instead.
Reference link: https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that currently Amplify only supports SSR for Next.JS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/server-side-rendering-amplify.html#ssr-Amplify-support

The solution on AWS would probably be to use Lambda https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-server-side-rendering-for-react-in-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 0):

**2023 November**

Now it support any SSR apps: https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/mobile/introducing-support-for-hosting-any-ssr-app-on-aws-amplify-hosting/